# driver.find_element_by_xpath does not click my element in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried many ways but driver doesnot clicking my element.

```
done=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='dimapply-btn']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", done)
```

and I have also tried with WebDriverWait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Done']"))).click()
```

I have also used (x,y) point.

```
done = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body')
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(done, 320, 430).click().perform()
```

My html code is:

```
<div class="btn-apply" data-ng-click="applyDimensionChanges()" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <button class="dimapply-btn">Done</button>
</div>
```

It does not throws any errors. just passes by my code and does not click.
please help me out. thank you in advance. i am solving this line for two days.

Comment: Javascript executer does not throw any exception, if it is not able to perform the action. Why aren't you using the selenium click() method? Did you check for iframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Done** button you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.btn-apply[data-ng-click^='applyDimensionChanges']>button.dimapply-btn"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='btn-apply' and starts-with(@data-ng-click, 'applyDimensionChanges')]/button[@class='dimapply-btn' and text()='Done']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```